# why is my didEnterRegion delegate not called?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

I am developing an app that checks for Beacons but I am having issues that my delegate is never run when I enter a region, I know the beacon is ok and broadcasting because I can see it in other beacon apps like "locate beacon"

I have configured the same UUID in the transmitter and the receiver app and I have double verified them so I am sure they are the same, below is my code that starts the locationManager and monitors for the region including the delegate.

Debugs tells me the monitoring is started correctly as per below

```
SelfCheckout[2977:845403] location Manager started to monitor regions: {(
CLBeaconRegion (identifier:'me.netwizards.office', uuid:39876A4B-43B2-4BE8-9A9C-41BAE913D56A, major:(null), minor:(null))
)}
```

Below is the class definition that includes the delegate

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```

-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Initialize location manager and set ourselves as the delegate
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

    // Create a NSUUID with the same UUID as the broadcasting beacon
    NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"39876A4B-43B2-4BE8-9A9C-41BAE913D56A"];

    // Setup a new region with that UUID and same identifier as the broadcasting beacon
    self.myBeaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid
                                                             identifier:@"me.netwizards.office"];

    // Tell location manager to start monitoring for the beacon region
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.myBeaconRegion];
    NSLog(@"location Manager started to monitor");
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion*)region
{
    NSLog(@"Did Enter Region");
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.myBeaconRegion];
}
```

Why is my delegate never called?

Comment: Is your beacon initially switched off?  Do you get a call to `monitoringDidFailForRegion`?

Comment: yes the beacon is initially turned off, I start my app and then enable the beacon, and no call to monitoringDidFailForRegion or didFailWithError

Comment: Are you already in the region when starting the monitoring? If so, you may not get notified as the device technically never crosses the threshold into the region.

Comment: I am next to the transmitter yes, so how can I detect beacons when I am already in the region? it seems weird though if the beacon is off when app starts and then I turn it on, the app cannot know I was out of region or the transmitter was powered on

Comment: If you turn on/off the beacon, it is an enter action.

Did you add `Privacy - Location Always Usage Description` to your Info.plist?
Have you accepted the Location Permission? 
Have you location services on?

Comment: Yes I added all the location strings into my Plist and the app asks for it on first start and I clicked allow

Comment: I can see in the settings that it is using the whileusingtheapp which is what I am asking for as I am testing in the foreground, should I change my location permission to always use? would that make a difference?

Comment: Try to add                                   self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

Comment: yes changing from inUse to alwaysAuth worked, now it works as expected but why? my app is always in the foreground anyway I don't understand what the difference is

Comment: This is just not stable it works sometimes, it is so strange, first time app starts it starts monitoring empty regions

Comment: Because beacon region monitoring occurs in the background as well as the foreground you must request "always" permission

Comment: ok I understand that now thanks, but this simply don't work every time, it works sometimes if the sun if behind the moon and no clouds in the air, I cannot get it to work every time, what could cause it to be unstable?